# Order of execution for multiple procs in Ruby

Tags: ruby, proc

I was trying out a silly example to get an understanding of multiple procs sent over to a method. However, one thing that amazed me was the order of execution. I looked at the Proc documentation but didn't really find an explanation (may be I didn't look closely enough).

Here is an example:

```
def my_block(a, b)
    a.call b.call
end

a = Proc.new { puts "hello" }
b = Proc.new { puts " world" }

my_block a, b
```

Output:

```
 world
hello
```

It seems like the proc execution when given more than one on a line executes from left to right. Can someone explain this behaviour in detail?

Comment: That is actually pretty interesting.  Now I am trying to look into why that happens!

Comment: Thank you @dane. Appreciate any help or inputs. `:)`

Comment: I was maybe thinking the compiler is shifting "<<" them into an array since they are on the same line and then the b.call is actually getting put ontop? @jaypal sigh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because this:

```
a.call b.call
```

is really:

```
a.call(b.call())
```

So the `b.call()` gets expanded (and run) first like in any ol' programming language, and the result of that is passed as a parameter to `a`.

You would hope this would give an error, but in Ruby extra parameter to a block don't result in errors (it is an error for a method, though)...

You can use a semicolon to explicitly tell ruby to start a new expression:

```
a.call; b.call
```

... but I would say that's pretty unidiomatic and "un-Ruby"...

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It's little hard to grasp the optional parens when you are coming from java! `:)`

Comment: @jaypalsingh if you are wondering why you don't see an error, it's because `call` receives a variadic parameter, or a any number of args. In this case it does nothing with them.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. `but in Ruby extra parameter to a block don't result in errors` is an important note for keeping in mind.

Comment: @jaypalsingh if you use a lambda instead of `Proc.new` you would see an error: `wrong number of arguments.`

Comment: @jaypalsingh I had a "huh?" moment about this for a few seconds as well ;-) IMHO leaving off the parens when you're not passing any arguments is a design mistake and can cause all sorts of edge conditions that go wrong... CoffeeScript, by the way, fixed this by allowing `a.call 'param'` but requiring the params when using no parameters, so you need `a.call()`, which provides the best of both worlds ... Ah well ...

Comment: Thanks @Mohamad for your insights. I was going through Baruco conference talks and John Cinnamond kinda stated that it's better to use lambdas for it's stricter checks.

Answer (score 3):

It's simply because you have them both on the same line so b.call is being called as a parameter to a.call. For this to work as you expect you need;

```
def my_block(a, b)
  a.call
  b.call
end
```